# How to get the value of various checkbox

Tags: javascript

I have created multiple checkbox with different names as seen in the code snippet and will like to get the values of each of them i.e if the user clicks on a checkbox the value 1 is stored and 0 if not clicked but I keep getting only the 0 value for all of them. It doesn't seem to be reading if I click it or not. I have tried various answers I have seen online and on this platform but to no avail.

My code snippet is:

```
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 border-pdf-td">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label for="telecommunication">
            <input name="telecommunication" type="hidden" value="0" />
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="telecommunication" />
            Telecommunication
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5 border-pdf-td">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label for="grocery">
            <input name="grocery" type="hidden" value="0" />
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="grocery" />
            Grocery and Supermarkets
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 border-pdf-d">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label for="petroleum">
            <input name="petroleum" type="hidden" value="0" />
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="petroleum" />
            Petroleum
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 border-pdf-d">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label for="ecommerce">
              <input name="ecommerce" type="hidden" value="0" />
              <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ecommerce" />
              E-Commerce
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 border-pdf-d">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label for="mailorder">
            <input name="mailorder" type="hidden" value="0" />
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="mailorder" />
            Mail order/telephone order (MOTO)
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The current state of my JavaScript code to get the values is

```
  var telecommunication = document.getElementsByName("telecommunication")[0].value;
  var grocery = document.getElementsByName("grocery")[0].value;
  var petroleum = document.getElementsByName("petroleum")[0].value;
  var ecommerce = document.getElementsByName("ecommerce")[0].value;
  var mailorder = document.getElementsByName("mailorder")[0].value;
```

I previously tried the code below but keep getting same results.

```
var telecommunication = document.querySelector('input[name="telecommunication"]:checked').value;
var grocery = document.querySelector('input[name="grocery"]:checked').value;
var petroleum = document.querySelector('input[name="petroleum"]:checked').value;
var ecommerce = document.querySelector('input[name="ecommerce"]:checked').value;
var mailorder = document.querySelector('input[name="mailorder"]:checked').value;
```

Please note that I have these checkbox and more on same form to get their values by their unique name.

Comment: "I have created multiple checkbox with different names as seen in the code snippet" – That's a PHP hack. Do you need this to work with a regular form submission to PHP too?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get the values with javascript and store them in my database using php.
The form contains various input fields with types as checkboxes, radio buttons, text and also textareas.
Everything seams to store fine in the database except from the checkboxes

Comment: You have pairs of inputs with the same name attribute value.  Either of your codes will only see the first one - the hidden ones.  You need to use [1] instead of [0] in your first code, or input[type=checkbox][name="xxx"].... in the second one

Comment: It might be way easier to use `radio` buttons instead if you need either send a `1` or a `0`.

Comment: @Rex you need to implement the "onclick" listener on your checkboxes, so that you know when their value change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need this

```
<input name="telecommunication" type="hidden" value="0" />
```

So grab the value

```
var telecommunication = document.querySelector('input[name="telecommunication"]:checked') ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a bad pattern of design for your form. If you want to send a `1` or a `0` then you should use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.
Checkboxes (and radios) are designed to be included in a request only when they are checked.

You can use a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) object to get all the values from the form.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('change', event => {
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  for (const [ name, value ] of formData) {
    console.log(`${name}:`, value);
  }
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<form>

  <div class="form-group">
    <h4>Telecommunication</h4>
    <label>
      Yes
      <input type="radio" value="1" name="telecommunication" checked />
    </label>
    <label>
      No
      <input type="radio" value="0" name="telecommunication" />
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <h4>Grocery and Supermarkets</h4>
    <label>
      Yes
      <input type="radio" value="1" name="grocery" checked />
    </label>
    <label>
      No
      <input type="radio" value="0" name="grocery" />
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <h4>Petroleum</h4>
    <label>
      Yes
      <input type="radio" value="1" name="petroleum" checked />
    </label>
    <label>
      No
      <input type="radio" value="0" name="petroleum" />
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <h4>E-Commerce</h4>
    <label>
      Yes
      <input type="radio" value="1" name="ecommerce" checked />
    </label>
    <label>
      No
      <input type="radio" value="0" name="ecommerce" />
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <h4>Mail order/telephone order (MOTO)</h4>
    <label>
      Yes
      <input type="radio" value="1" name="mailorder" checked />
    </label>
    <label>
      No
      <input type="radio" value="0" name="mailorder" />
    </label>
  </div>
  
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but checkbox is the design I was told to use.